# String.CharacterView - how to convert to String

Tags: swift, swift3

I have tried the following:

```
let str = self.passwordLabel.text?.characters.dropLast()
let s = String(describing: str)
```

But it give me the following:

```
"Optional(Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: Optional(0x0000618000051e10), _countAndFlags: 9223372036854775810, _owner: Optional(Swift._HeapBufferStorage<Swift._StringBufferIVars, Swift.UInt16>)), _coreOffset: 0))"
```

I just wanted to remove the last char from the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unwrap the optional string and don't use the `describing` initializer.

```
if let passwordText = self.passwordLabel.text {
    let s = String(passwordText.characters.dropLast())
}
```

or if it's guaranteed that `text` is not `nil`

```
let s = String(self.passwordLabel.text!.characters.dropLast())
```

Comment: Not using describing gives me 'init' has been renamed to 'init(describing:)

Comment: Use exactly the syntax as in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `String(describing:...)` and unwrap the optional `str`.

```
let passwordLabel = UILabel()
passwordLabel.text = "TEXT1"
if let str = passwordLabel.text?.characters.dropLast() {
    let s = String(str)
    print(s)
}
```

Prints: `TEXT`